# Message box with cancel button only

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can we have a message box with cancel button only ? If so , any hints ? Is there a built in api method to get only messagebox with cancel button alone/

How to create custom modal dialog ? Any Links ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a thread-local CBT hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to customize the `MessageBox()` dialog however you want.

For instance, you can change the text of the "OK" button to say "Cancel" instead, eg:

```
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wParam);
        SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDOK), TEXT("Cancel"));
        return 0;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

{
    ...
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(&CBTHookProc), NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    int iResult = MessageBox(..., MB_OK);
    if (iResult == IDOK) iResult = IDCANCEL;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    ...
}
```

Or you can hide the standard "OK" button and let the dialog still use its native "Cancel" button:

```
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wParam);
        ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDOK), SW_HIDE);
        // optionally reposition the IDCANCEL child window as well....
        return 0;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

{
    ...
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(&CBTHookProc), NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    int iResult = MessageBox(..., MB_OKCANCEL);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    ...
}
```

**Update:** on Vista and later, you can (and should) use [`TaskDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540.aspx) or [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx) instead of `MessageBox()`.  Task dialogs are much more flexible, including the ability to let you specify which buttons are on the dialog, and even use custom buttons.  So you can easily display a Cancel-only dialog without using any hooks at all, eg:

```
TaskDialog(..., TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON, ..., &iResult);
```

```
TASKDIALOGCONFIG TaskConfig = {0};
TaskConfig.cbSize = sizeof(TaskConfig);
TaskConfig.dwCommonButtons = TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
...
TaskDialogIndirect(&TaskConfig, &iResult, ...);
```

Comment: You're missing some semicolons at the end of your CallNextHookEx lines. SO wont let me edit it because it's such a small change.

Never the less: awesome answer!

Comment: I added the missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

For a message box that only displays a notification, I believe it's convention to use an "OK" box.   Cancel seems a bit, redundant?   
But i suppose if you wanted to do it, you could do it by defining your own message box object and specify the buttons yourself using "Cancel" as the text attribute.

C++ nor any other language has a built-in function for defining message boxes with just "Cancel" again, as "OK" is the convention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with MessabeBox. You can simple create your own dialog and add a single cancel button.

You can also have a look at this link

[XMessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox)

It may solve your problem