# Show Yes/No messagebox where No is grayed out win32api C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to show a simple Yes/No messagebox but gray out/inactive the No button.  With the C  win32api

Comment: Can you explain why you want to show an option that the user can't click?  If there's only one choice, there's no reason to show a messagebox at all...

Comment: As it can be comical given context of the question

Comment: This question is fairly bogus. All the same, take a look at XMessageBox. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox

Comment: [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox) hooks the message box to change the button text.  You could easily extend it to disable the buttons.

Comment: Like many Windows components, a MessageBox is designed for a very specific set of circumstances. Your requirements do not fit those circumstances and you won't be able to use the built-in function.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570201/message-box-with-cancel-button-only. should be simple enough to adapt for your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) with a thread-local hook to capture the `MessageBox()` dialog's HWND, then you can use [`EnableWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291.aspx) to disable the button.

Here is how to do it using `SetWindowsHookEx()`:

```
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE )
    {
        HWND hDlg = (HWND) wParam;
        HWND hBtnWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDNO);
        if (hBtnWnd != NULL)
            EnableWindow(hBtnWnd, FALSE);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

{
    //...

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test"), TEXT("Test"), MB_YESNO);

    if (hHook != NULL)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);

    //...
}
```

Here is how to do it using `SetWinEventHook()`:

```
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if( event == EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART )
    {
        HWND hBtnWnd = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDNO);
        if (hBtnWnd != NULL)
            EnableWindow(hBtnWnd, FALSE);
    }
}

{
    //...

    HRESULT hRes = CoInitialize(NULL);

    HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART, NULL, &WinEventProc, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test"), TEXT("Test"), MB_YESNO);

    if (hHook != NULL)
        UnhookWinEvent(hHook);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        CoUninitialize();

    //...
}
```

Comment: Fortunately, you won't have to roll your own message box from scratch when you have XMessageBox.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, why add a dependency on outside code when it's so simple just to create a dialog with two buttons and some text in it?

Comment: Fair enough. I work in a project that already has XMessageBox and we use it for everything, so I guess my mindset is skewed in that direction. It's really a great thing to have in your toolbox, but if you don't need it for any other purpose, sure, it's overkill here.

Comment: You can disable a MessageBox one from another thread, can't you?

Comment: You can manipulate the standard `MessageBox()` dialog, just use a thread-local message hook or CBT hook to run your code while the dialog is running, then you can do whatever you want to it since you will have access to its `HWND`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You should provide an answer, because I have no idea how to do that. I've modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Or use an event hook so you don't have to inject anything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @chris: that is still a hook. Whether you use `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()`, you are still injecting code to be executed while `MessageBox()` is running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I was pretty much referencing [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx).

Comment: @chris: thread-local hooks do not need to be in DLLs and are not injected. Using MSAA helps when you need to hook other processes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Oh dang, I forgot this was even being used for the same process. I *never* use hooks aside from every process in my endeavours. Accessibility is quite nice for free programs that show messages to buy the full version when they start and such.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I can't provide an answer of my own because the question has been closed. But I have updated your answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Wow, I suck :p I'm going to delete my answer in favour of this.