# Show dialog from C++ from a VC6 DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dialog

I have an old VC6 old DLL (without MFC) with some published functions.
Until now, a simple message box with OK/Cancel buttons was enough.
Now, I want to display a CANCEL button to offer the user the posibility of canceling an action, but I cannot use standard message boxes as no one offers a 'just CANCEL button' option.
Then I want to show a simple Dialog, from the DLL.
What would be the best approach to show this dialog?

Comment: This worked like a charm:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570201/message-box-with-cancel-button-only

Comment: Avoid non-standard UI, it only confuses the user.  Just word the message correctly so that an "OK" response makes sense.